# How can I fix 'Unable to write into user settings' error when changing VSCode theme in settings.json?

Tags: themes

I had problem with my vscode when i try to change the theme

> "Unable to write into user settings. Please open the user settings to
> correct errors/warnings in it and try again."

this is my settings.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "Build C/C++ Project",
        "type": "cpp",
        "sources": [
          "${fileDirname}/**/*.cc"
        ],
        "output": "${workspaceFolder}/debug/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "group": "build"
      }
    ]  
  }  
  
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark"
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe"
}
```

please help me, thank you very much

change themes
correct error